Getting 'sos array must be shape (n_sections, 6)' when trying to apply signal.sosfilt to data
I'm to apply my Butterworth filter to an array using sosfilt as below:
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import sklearn
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import scipy as sp
import itertools as it

Fs = 30000     # sampling rate of the signal in Hz
dt = 1/Fs
gain = .5      # gain of the signal
x = pd.read_csv('/Users/michael/Downloads/neural_data_science_data_package/nda_ex_1.csv', header=0, names=('Ch1', 'Ch2', 'Ch3', 'Ch4'))

description = x.describe()
print(description)

def filterSignal(x, Fs, low, high, order):
#   Each column in x is one
#   recording channel. Fs is the sampling frequency. low and high specify the passband in Hz.
    relativelow=low/(Fs/2)
    relativehigh=high/(Fs/2)
    Wn=[relativelow,relativehigh]
    # filter the signal independently for each column in x as each is one channel
    
    
    sos = signal.butter(order, Wn, 'bp', fs=Fs, output='sos')
    print(sos.shape)
    np.apply_along_axis(signal.sosfilt, 0, x, sos)

filterSignal(x, Fs, 2000, 10000, 2)

sos.shape gives me (2, 6) when order=2, which may be wrong. The error code is given below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/michael/VSCode/Berenslab/berenslab/lab1.py", line 32, in <module>
    filterSignal(x, Fs, 2000, 10000, 2)
  File "/Users/michael/VSCode/Berenslab/berenslab/lab1.py", line 30, in filterSignal
    np.apply_along_axis(signal.sosfilt, 0, x, sos)
  File "/Users/michael/VSCode/Berenslab/berenslab/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/_shape_base_impl.py", line 384, in apply_along_axis
    res = asanyarray(func1d(inarr_view[ind0], *args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/michael/VSCode/Berenslab/berenslab/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/signal/_signaltools.py", line 4316, in sosfilt
    sos, n_sections = _validate_sos(sos)
  File "/Users/michael/VSCode/Berenslab/berenslab/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/signal/_filter_design.py", line 730, in _validate_sos
    raise ValueError('sos array must be shape (n_sections, 6)')
ValueError: sos array must be shape (n_sections, 6)

I'm not sure if the issue is the n_sections part, because the sos array is shaped (2, 6). Thanks for any help.

Did you try just using sosfilt directly?  With the axis parameter instead of np.apply_along_axis(

This appears to be due to the somewhat convoluted way that apply_along_axis() passes arguments to sosfilt(). I think the problem may be here that apply_along_axis() implictly assumes that the first argument into the function to apply is the array, which isn't the case for sosfilt()
Just call sosfilt() directly.
x = signal.sosfilt(sos, x, axis=0)


Thank you this fixed the issue.
